# What workaround can I use with ambigous wildcard patterns in Struts (prior to v 2.1.9)?

Tags: struts2, design-patterns, wildcard

I have a problem finding the right wildcard pattern to extract parts of my URL into action parameters in Struts.

This is how I set up the action. The intent of the pattern is to capture the last two path elements and then everything that might precede them.

```
<action name="**/*/*" class="com.example.ObjectAction">
  <param name="filter">{1}</param>
  <param name="type">{2}</param>
  <param name="id">{3}</param>
</action>
```

Calling it with the URL `channels/123/transmissions/456` I get the following result (the action just sets the input parameters on a POJO and returns that as XML):

```
<result>
    <filter>channels/123/transmissions</filter>
    <id/>
    <type>456</type>
</result>
```

It should be:

```
<result>
    <filter>channels/123</filter>
    <id>456</id>
    <type>transmissions</type>
</result>
```

Now, because `**` matches all characters *including* the slash, I guess my pattern allows more than one way to match the URL, and Struts happens to pick one that leaves the `id` empty. Is the behaviour for multiple possible matches defined somewhere? Can I make the pattern less ambigous? Are there alternative ways of doing this?

I'm running Struts 2.0.8. Upgrading to 2.1.9 would give me regex matching, but I got into trouble with Struts' dependencies and my OSGi environment when I went past 2.0.8, so I'd like to stick to that version for now.

Comment: Is this still unresolved? If so you might want to submit this as an issue in struts2 community.

Comment: @doctrey - An alternative route for me is to solve my upgrade issues and use regex matching introduced in 2.1.x, but for me, and for my version, yes, it is still unresolved. If a working solution is already released, I doubt that the Struts people would care.

Comment: A sound "You can't do this, and here's why" *is* an acceptable answer, though not one I'd like. :) I mean, I guess I *could* upgrade.

Comment: What is the reason for not upgrading? I can understand if you were using struts 1, but if you were using struts2 in a normal way the upgrade should be painless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think struts2 wildcards were not mature enough at that point.
[Here](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/wildcard-mappings.html) and [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/wildcard-mappings.html) do not provide any guidance on more complex patterns. But since `**` matches everything **including** slashes, my guess is struts2 treats everything up to last slash as a unit hence setting it to the first placeholder and set the last wildcard to the second one. That's why the third placeholder remains null.
I suggest you to upgrade since (and you perfectly know it) struts 2.1+ provide pattern matching which could be more helpful in your case.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not sure which version you need to upgrade to, but the NamedVariablePatternMatcher would do exactly what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772737/hidden-features-of-struts-2-framework/4837917#4837917

Answer (score 0):

This is more general advice than specific to structs, but here goes.

If you append an additional / to the URL (Which could be done automatically at some point in your testing structure), then the greedy result would be what you are seeing.

I would double check to ensure in some way that you are requesting the URL you think you are, or see if there is a way to specify + (aka a non-empty result)

EDIT: To answer the overall question, it is hard to tell whether a match is greedy or not, since often times parsers will return the first "valid" result, which may be equivalent to the greedy one depending on where you have it.

Comment: Yes, I checked that I'm calling the URL I think I am. Appending "/" leads to the whole path ending up in `filter`. I think my problem depends a lot on some details in how Struts handles this.

Comment: I rephrased my question almost completely after I got a clearer picture of what my problem is. Sorry if that made your answer look weird.

Comment: If 2.1.9 is giving a better error message, then try getting it to work in that version then backport, if it is using the same logic with some additional checks then this trick should work. If it is a different method, then obviously it won't

Comment: Guvante, there is no error message. The URL is parsed, and, from a technical point of view, correctly. It just isn't working as I intend it to.